# How to detect when div text appears with MutationObserver?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers

I use the following code to understand when `div` element is loaded:

```
const callback = function (mutationsList, observer) {
  
    for (let node of mutation.addedNodes) {    
      if (!(node instanceof HTMLElement)) continue;    
      if (node.matches('div[class*="textLayer"]')) {    
        ...    
      }    
    }        
};

const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
observer.observe(target, config);
```

But the page loads its content later. So, I should wait to `textLayer` content to appear:

```
<div class="textLayer" style="width: 554px; height: 783px;"></div>
```

transforms to

```
<div class="textLayer" style="width: 554px; height: 783px;">
    <span style="left: 27.9328px; top: 27.2773px">Some text</span>
    <span style="left: 27.9328px; top: 63.4428px; font-size: 13.0353px; font-family: sans-serif; transform: scaleX(0.905998);">Some other text I am interested in:</span>
    <span style="left: 27.9328px; top: 79.2713px">0349602902309000000123456</span>
    ...
 </div>
```

How should I achieve it? Is the text value should be monitored as attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to observe also the changes in the children of the textLayer div. So adjust the observer configuration

```
    const config = {
     attributes: true,       // attribute changes
     childList: true,        // additions/removals of child nodes
     characterData: true,    // changes in text
     subtree: true           // watch for all sub elements
    };
```

Also you can make adjustments to your callback function if you want to:

```
    const callback = function (mutationsList, observer) {
        for(let mutation of mutationsList) {
            if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
                // Handle added nodes
                for(let node of mutation.addedNodes) {
                    if(node instanceof HTMLElement) {
                        console.log(node);
                    }
                }
    
                // Handle removed nodes
                for(let node of mutation.removedNodes) {
                    if(node instanceof HTMLElement) {
                        console.log(node);
                    }
                }
            }
            // Handle text changes
            if (mutation.type === 'characterData') {
                console.log(mutation.target.textContent);
            }
        }
    };

    const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
    observer.observe(target, config);
```